# Should a class be able to output its contents or should another class do that?

Tags: c++, oop, io, output

This is a "best design" question. I know there is many ways to do that. The question is, which is favourable for which reasons.

Generally speaking: I have a bunch of classes that contain data in different types. Each class is a little bit different from the others. At some point I might want to output the data contained in these classes, each class instance at a different point in time. I see two ways of implementing this:

a) write a "output()" method of some sort for each of the classes. When I wnat to output, I must rely on this method to exist.

b) write a class "OutputClasses" which has a method "output()" which handles the output differently for each class

Which one would be the "standard" or expected way? One of the above or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recommended way is to have:

```
ostream& YourClass::Output(ostream& os) const;
```

member function in each class as well as "standalone" overloaded << operator to call it:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const YourClass&c)
{
    return c.Output(os);
}
```

Source: ["Exceptional C++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615622) by Herb Sutter, Item 20. Class Mechanics

[Sutter’s Mill](http://herbsutter.com/category/c/gotw/page/3/)

Comment: Could you post the source of this? Dr Dobbs? Thanks so far!